# (android) How I understand touch the advertisement in code?

Tags: android, admob, ontouchlistener

I want to know how many user click the ads on my application.Because of this I want to write code to understand touching ads.

CODE :

```
 final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.advertisement);
        touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                 counter++;

                return false;
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needn't do complicated things to intercept the click events with admob for android. There is an event in `AdListener` which is intended exactly to intercept the click events: `onPresentScreen(Ad ad)`. I'm actually using it in my app to record click statistics in a database. It works.

More information: [com.google.ads.AdListener](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/intermediate#adlistener)

Comment: I add adlistener and I write some code onpresentscreen but never works.I mean onpresenscreen doesnt work I implement adlistener

Comment: when I write this :   adView.setAdListener(this); it works thanks